# Accessing Devise Config Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails app, what would be the way to access a Devise config variable directly from a view?

I want to show `config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for` from Devise's `:confirmable` module. This variable is set in `devise.rb` initializer:

```
Devise.setup do
  config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 3.days
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: suggest `Devise.remember_for` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34621814/1536309

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The configurations on `devise.rb` file are replicated on your Devise model, so if your Devise resource is `User`, you should be able to access it through `User.allow_unconfirmed_access_for`.

So, create an instance variable on your controller and assign this value to it, and then you'll be able to show it on your view.

Comment: This is still true for me on Devise 3.5.2.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is no longer correct. For more recent Devise versions, the config options are tacked on to the main `Devise` module, e.g. `Devise.allow_unconfirmed_access_for`.

Comment: `User.allow_unconfirmed_access_for` still works for me on Devise 3.5.2.

Comment: confirmed also in devise 3.5.10. actually they both work

Answer (score 4):

This answers a similar question:

OmniAuth config is stored in an omniauths_config object within a nested stragety object

```
Devise.omniauth_configs
```

returns:

```
{:facebook=>
  #<Devise::OmniAuth::Config:0x007fa6db95aa68
  ....
```

then access via symbol:

`Devise.omniauth_configs[:facebook].strategy`

```
{"setup"=>true,
 "skip_info"=>false,
 "client_id"=>nil,
 "client_secret"=>nil,
 "client_options"=>{"site"=>"https://graph.facebook.com", "authorize_url"=>"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth", "token_url"=>"/oauth/access_token"},
 "authorize_params"=>{},
 "authorize_options"=>[:scope, :display, :auth_type],
 "token_params"=>{"parse"=>:query},
 "token_options"=>[],
 "auth_token_params"=>{},
 "provider_ignores_state"=>false,
 "access_token_options"=>{"header_format"=>"OAuth %s", "param_name"=>"access_token"},
 "scope"=>"email,public_profile,publish_actions",
 "info_fields"=>"email, first_name, last_name",
 "name"=>"facebook"}
```