# How to set Devise config values within model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models using Devise. Everything's properly scoped and working fine.

Now I want to set several config values differently for each model. For example, in one model I want to set `allow_unconfirmed_access_for` for a few days, and in the other I do not want to allow any such unconfirmed access.

This is possible per Devise's own documentation at the top of `config/initializers/devise.rb`...

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth.
# Many of these configuration options can be set straight in your model.
```

What's the syntax necessary to set variables within a model, as opposed to the initializer? I currently have this inside my model...

```
# Model Foo
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
end

# Model Bar
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 0.days
end
```

and it does not appear to be working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the advice from [a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231687/accessing-devise-config-variables-from-a-view), I learned that these values are placed inside of the model to which Devise is applied. So we're just dealing with normal class variables.

I was able to get the desired results by setting the variables like so...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable,
          :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable,
          :confirmable, :recoverable, :lockable

  # override Devise default config settings
  self.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # ...
```